# How to dynamically add new fixtures to a test based on the fixture signature of a test

Tags: python, pytest

So what I would like to achieve is mocking functions in various modules automatically with pytest. So I defined this in my conftest.py:

```
import sys
import __builtin__
from itertools import chain


# Fixture factory magic START
NORMAL_MOCKS = [
    "logger", "error", "logging", "base_error", "partial"]
BUILTIN_MOCKS = ["exit"]


def _mock_factory(name, builtin):
    def _mock(monkeypatch, request):
        module = __builtin__ if builtin else request.node.module.MODULE
        ret = Mock()
        monkeypatch.setattr(module, name, ret)
        return ret
    return _mock


iterable = chain(
    ((el, False) for el in NORMAL_MOCKS),
    ((el, True) for el in BUILTIN_MOCKS))
for name, builtin in iterable:
    fname = "mock_{name}".format(name=name)
    _tmp_fn = pytest.fixture(name=fname)(_mock_factory(name, builtin))
    _tmp_fn.__name__ = fname
    setattr(
        sys.modules[__name__], 
        "mock_{name}".format(name=name), _tmp_fn)
# Fixture normal factory magic END
```

This works and all, but I would like to omit the usage of the `NORMAL_MOCKS` and `BUILTIN_MOCKS` lists. So basically in a pytest hook I should be able to see that say there is a `mock_foo` fixture, but it's not registered yet, so I create a mock for it with the factory and register it. I just couldn't figure out how to do this. Basically I was looking into the `pytest_runtest_setup` function, but could not figure out how to do the actual fixture registration. So basically I would like to know with which hook/call can I register new fixture functions programatically from this hook.

Comment: The final solution based on the advice of @sergey-vasilyev can be found here -> https://gist.github.com/dpapp-hortonworks/6224068ffc11d18c500b75a861941dfb

Answer (score 4):

One of the ways is to parameterize the tests at the collection/generation stage, i.e. before the test execution begins: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/parametrize.html

```
# conftest.py 
import pytest

def mock_factory(name):
    return name

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    for name in metafunc.fixturenames:
        if name.startswith('mock_'):
            metafunc.parametrize(name, [mock_factory(name[5:])])

# test_me.py
def test_me(request, mock_it):
    print(mock_it)
```

A very simple solution. But the downside is that the test is reported as parametrized when it actually is not:

```
$ pytest -s -v -ra
====== test session starts ======

test_me.py::test_me[it] PASSED

====== 1 passed in 0.01 seconds ======
```

---

To fully simulate the function args without the parametrization, you can make a less obvious trick:

```
# conftest.py
import pytest

def mock_factory(name):
    return name

@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_protocol(item, nextitem):
    for name in item.fixturenames:
        if name.startswith('mock_') and name not in item.funcargs:
            item.funcargs[name] = mock_factory(name[5:])
    yield
```

The `pytest_runtest_setup` hook is also a good place for this, as long as I've just tried.

**Note** that you do not register the fixture in that case. It is too late for the fixture registration, as all the fixtures are gathered and prepared much earlier at the collection/parametrization stages. In this stage, you can only execute the tests and provide the values. It is your responsibility to calculate the fixture values and to destroy them afterward.

Comment: That's a really nice solution. Thank you!(can't upvote with this account due to low reputation, I'll vote with my normal account). Is it possible to access the `request` object in the `pytest_generate_tests` function. I would like to mock functions in a specific module which I define in a variable in a testing module.

Comment: I've realized that the https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/parametrize.html#the-metafunc-object has a module member which is what I'd need from the request object. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The snippet below is a pragmatic solution to "how to dynamically add fixtures".

Disclaimer: I don't have expertise on `pytest`. I'm not saying this is what `pytest` was designed for, I just looked at the source code and came up with this and it seems to work. The fact that I use "private" attributes means it might not work with all versions (currently I'm on `pytest` `7.1.3`)

```py
from _pytest.fixtures import FixtureDef
from _pytest.fixtures import SubRequest
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)  # autouse is relevant, as then the fixture registration happens in-time. It's too late if requiring the fixture without autouse e.g. like `@pytest.mark.usefixtures("add_fixture_dynamically")`
def add_fixture_dynamically(request: SubRequest):
    """
    Conditionally and dynamically adds another fixture. It's conditional on the presence of:

        @pytest.mark.my_mark()
    """
    marker = request.node.get_closest_marker("my_mark")

    # don't register fixture if marker is not present:
    if marker is None:
        return

    def your_fixture():  # the name of the fixture must match the parameter name, like other fixtures
        return "hello"

    # register the fixture just-in-time
    request._fixturemanager._arg2fixturedefs[your_fixture.__name__] = [
        FixtureDef(
            argname=your_fixture.__name__,
            func=your_fixture,
            scope="function",
            fixturemanager=request._fixturemanager,
            baseid=None,
            params=None,
        ),
    ]

    yield  # runs the test. Could be wrapped in try/except/finally
 

# suppress warning (works if this and `add_fixture_dynamically` are in `conftest.py`)
def pytest_configure(config):
    """Prevents printing of the warning 'PytestUnknownMarkWarning: Unknown pytest.mark.<fixture_name>'"""
    config.addinivalue_line("markers", "my_mark")


@pytest.mark.my_mark()
def test_adding_fixture_dynamically(your_fixture):
    assert your_fixture == "hello"
```